# (Blender 2.8) Smoke not showing in Physics Properties

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, properties

The smoke physics is missing and I don't know how can I fix that. Thanks for helping me !

Here's the screen of the physics properties.
[image]

Comment: You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page, instead of asking users go through links just to understand your question. Use the tools on the site to upload images directly. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question to modify it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png).

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the smoke simulation is now under fluid for 2.82

Answer (score 0):

Now Blender doesn't show smoke because it is under fluid physics. Select fluid in the physics properties, and set as flow and type to smoke.